# How can I install MongoDB community server on my Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: mongodb, 23.10

As per the MongoDB docs, *MongoDB 7.0 Community Edition* supports the following 64-bit Ubuntu LTS releases on x86_64 architecture:

22.04 LTS ("Jammy")

20.04 LTS ("Focal")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me add some details to [Rinzwind's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1499955/1104552).

Import the MongoDB Repository:

```
wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-7.0.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

Create the list file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-7.0.list` for your Ubuntu 23.10. You might use the sources for 22.04 (Jammy) as a workaround:

```
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/7.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-7.0.list
```

Update the local package database:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install MongoDB Packages:

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

Start MongoDB:

```
sudo systemctl start mongod
```

Verify that MongoDB has started successfully:

```
sudo systemctl status mongod
```

Good luck!

Comment: This is the same answer as in the official documentation. And the problem is that it seems to not work on other versions than the listed, it's not a workaraound. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#std-label-install-mdb-community-ubuntu

Comment: Yup this worked for me on Ubuntu 23.04 (Lunar Lobster)

Answer (score 3):

The same way as you install it for the last LTS your non-LTS stems from. In this case 22.04. Basically when you add the repository for it it will add "jammy" as the version.

The reason they only list LTS is because installing server software tends to mean you use an LTS.